# onchange in a form using formik the value of the field is not updated

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm new to react, and I'm trying to apply validations to a form.

For some reason when adding the property:

```
onChange={onChange}
```

I want to send the values to the parent component. That's why I'm using the onchange.

Nothing I write is shown in my text fields, why does this happen?

[image]

```
export const Son = props => {
  const { onChange } = props;
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        fullname: "",
        email: ""
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        fullname: Yup.string()
          .min(2, "Your name is too short")
          .required("Please enter your full name"),
        email: Yup.string()
          .email("The email is incorrect")
          .required("Please enter your email")
      })}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        const timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(values);
          setSubmitting(false);

          clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }, 1000);
      }}
    >
      {({
        values,
        errors,
        touched,
        handleSubmit,
        isSubmitting,
        validating,
        valid
      }) => {
        return (
          <Form name="contact" method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="fullname">
              Fullname
              <Field
                type="text"
                name="fullname"
                autoComplete="name"
                placeholder="your fullname"
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </label>
            {<ErrorMessage name="fullname">{msg => <p>{msg}</p>}</ErrorMessage>}

            {/*errors.fullname && touched.fullname && <p>{errors.fullname}</p>*/}
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="email">
              Email
              <Field
                type="email"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                placeholder="your email"
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </label>
            <ErrorMessage name="email">{msg => <p>{msg}</p>}</ErrorMessage>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" disabled={!valid || isSubmitting}>
              {isSubmitting ? `Submiting...` : `Submit`}
            </button>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qotvwb?file=components/son_component.js

Answer (score 0):

you're not using the formik [handleChange](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#handlechange-e-reactchangeevent-any-void) at all.

I highlighted the changes [that I made in https://stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qkjqga?file=components/son_component.js)
[image]

and you can test this working [here](https://react-qotvwb.stackblitz.io/)

Comment: Friend, I'm a little confused, I'm new to this. If you help me I will learn how to solve it. I was trying to send my form to the parent component every time it is updated, but I think it is best to send it completely when I "submit", can you please show me how

Comment: Thank you, sorry for this question. How can I see the source code?

Comment: if you want to pass something to the parent component, let say the Son component, you can either get the values on the onSubmit callback (values argument) or override one of the [Formik callbacks](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation#when-does-validation-run)

Comment: thanks, how can i see the source code? I only see the result ..

Comment: I wanted to ask you, why does the submit button never activate?

Comment: @yavg can you [check again](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qkjqga?file=components/son_component.js)? I just saved your project in https://stackblitz.com/ with the fix

Comment: Thank you very much, I still don't understand how I can send my form to the father ..